# MySQL - Storing Times and Comparison with Dates

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm accessing an API that has a train schedule, which returns `arrival_time`.  The Arrival Time is in 24 hr format i.e `15:24:56`.

I can either store these as MySQL `TIME` types, or I may store them as integers in seconds (seconds since midnight).

However, I'm running into one issue:  When I access this data, I want to pull the next train times compared to the current time.  So lets says current date/time is `2016-02-14 23:52:30`. Since it's close to midnight, it won't recognize `01:20:30` as being later than the current time.

How do I handle this situation?  My first thought was to pull all possible `Arrival Time` values from the database, and create `DateTime` objects in my code (PHP) that place those times in today's Date.  Then, if I get to a point where there's less than X amount of 'Upcoming Times', take the same set of times and add one day to them and continue.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method of pulling the "next" train times:

```
select s.*
from schedules s
order by arrival_time > curtime() desc,
         arrival_time
limit 1;
```

Comment: @dtj . . . Yes.  That is what this query does.

Comment: Ah, I now see how this works.  Very succinct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Compute (later time) - (earlier time).  Then, if you get a negative number, add 24 hours.

```
mysql> SELECT @earlier := TIME_TO_SEC('23:52:30'), @later := TIME_TO_SEC('01:20:30');
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| @earlier := TIME_TO_SEC('23:52:30') | @later := TIME_TO_SEC('01:20:30') |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                               85950 |                              4830 |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT @diff := @later - @earlier;
+----------------------------+
| @diff := @later - @earlier |
+----------------------------+
|                     -81120 |
+----------------------------+

mysql> SELECT @real_diff := IF(@diff < 0, @diff + 86400, @diff);
+---------------------------------------------------+
| @real_diff := IF(@diff < 0, @diff + 86400, @diff) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                              5280 |
+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(@real_diff);
+-------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(@real_diff) |
+-------------------------+
| 01:28:00                |
+-------------------------+
```

(Of course, this can/should be shortened for use in your code.)